# How can I get the last two digits of any 3+ digit integer?

Tags: c#, parsing, int

I'm trying to get the last two digits of an int that is a minimum of 3 digits long. Here is my (rather sloppy) attempt:

```
char[] number = num.ToString().ToCharArray();
int firstnum;
int secondnum;
string strLastTwoDigits = "";
int intLastTwoDigits;
firstnum = number[number.ToString().Length - 1];
secondnum = number[number.ToString().Length - 2];

strLastTwoDigits = (firstnum.ToString() + secondnum.ToString());
intLastTwoDigits = int.Parse(strLastTwoDigits);
```

The `num` variable is the number I'm trying to get the last two digits of. I'm trying to turn them into strings and use the string functions to do it, probably not the way it's done. The logic to check whether it's 3 digits or more isn't included, I don't need help with that, just getting those last two digits.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you need those two numbers as a String? Or do you plan to convert them back to a number.
Because if you want to have a number at the end, just use the modulo- operator %.
You can find an example on how to use it here: https://www.dotnetperls.com/modulo

Edit: to state the obvious: last2 = number % 100;

Answer (score 4):

Just perform a [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division).

```
var intLastTwoDigits = num % 100;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `modulo` of that number, it should be something like

```
int lastTwoDigits = num % 100;
```

This function will divide `num / 100`and gives you the rest as integer.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the last to digits as int, you could just use modulo:

```
int lasttwo = num % 100;
```

the modulo operator (%) will return you the remainder of the division of one integer is by another - in this case your number divided by 100 - the remainder will always be the last two digits

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use strings for that, [`string.Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) method will help you

```cs
var numString = num.ToString();
var strLastTwoDigits = numString.Substring(numString.Length - 2, 2);
var intLastTwoDigits = int.Parse(strLastTwoDigits);
```

Another (and more simpler option) is to use remainder `%` [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#remainder-operator) for that

```cs
int intLastTwoDigits = num % 100;
```

You get a remainder of division into 100, because you need the 2 last digits